# I'm struggling to make my code work but with no results

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    north.innerHTML += "<div  onclick='remove()' style='display:inline-block; position:relative;'>" + 
                            "<img width='50px' style='cursor:pointer' height='100px'src=path"+player1[i]+".png'/>" + 
                       "</div>";
```

The problem I'm encountering is in the `onclick` attribute of the div's I'm inserting. 
When using `onclick='remove()'` the script works, but when i change the function to be executed with some other function declared by me it doesn't work.

I initially thought there may be a problem with the function i declared, but it doesn't work even with simple function as:

```
function example()
{
    prompt('example');
}
```

Any suggestions?
This is a link to the script :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B44rvU_T40BTVGN2V1RmVWdSS28/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Where is the function declared? Post a fuller example. Also you should rethink how you are structuring things.

Comment: where is which function declared? 
i'm a beginner in Javascript so excuse my poor Structuring :P 
the function remove() isthe standard method of javascript object and it executes just fine. 
the problem arises when i try to call another function declared inside the same js file

Comment: @AmarildoLikmeta See my answer, I am sure it will help you

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question (the part that is not working). It's hard to troubleshoot with only pieces of the puzzle - for example, can you add the other function that you are trying to call (the one that fails)

Comment: @AmarildoLikmeta Does it work if you declare it like this `window.example = function() {...}`?

Comment: @rixo 28 does the call to the function in attribute onclick change?

Comment: @Teemu but it does work when i call method remove() 
why is that? 
how would you suggest to do it with

     addEvenetListener